# Popup error: "openjdk-11.0.2 is damaged and can't be opened" on mac os ventura

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, java-11, macos-ventura

jdk 11 was fine on my mac os Mojave. On upgrading to Mac OS Ventura, I started seeing this popup error:

[image]

openjdk-11.0.2 is damaged and can't be opened.I uninstalled and reinstalled openjdk11 using brew but still get the same error:

```
$ brew uninstall openjdk@11
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.16.1_1... (678 files, 298.8MB)

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.261.12 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_191 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

$ brew install openjdk@11
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/manifests/11.0.16.1_1
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/66d77b9adc57a7f85fca1b4c90e6187f64aa336a0777d7dc1014151d925df3d8--openjdk@11-11.0.16.1_1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/blobs/sha256:4157114f6dd128b93d0732559787f191678d2d496476e19855a03d0f226aa50c
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/853c10b19f8f8cd779b49261c60a74abf52e9fea1067d934c45549bea2b8ed3e--openjdk@11--11.0.16.1_1.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openjdk@11--11.0.16.1_1.ventura.bottle.tar.gz

==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk

openjdk@11 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have openjdk@11 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openjdk@11 you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/include"

==> Summary
�  /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.16.1_1: 678 files, 298.8MB
==> Running `brew cleanup openjdk@11`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Answer (score 2):

For recent MacOS releases (I believe Catalina and newer), the key is the following command (note you may have to adjust the path for your flavor of JDK - this one is for GraalVM):

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-javaV-XX.Y.Z
```

It's outlined nicely on the [graalvm/homebrew-tap install instructions](https://github.com/graalvm/homebrew-tap).

Comment: This worked for me with a non-graal downloaded JDK I was trying to get IntelliJ to use.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all openjdk 11 directories using rm

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

&

```
/usr/local/Cellar/
```

and reinstalled openjdk11 using:

```
 brew install openjdk@11
```

Now, no more popup errors.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation is always your best bet. I have run into such issues couple of times before as well.